# Insert new line in a string in data fetched from firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js

i want to insert a new line in a string that I fetch from database. Using firebase as database

I have already tried using br tag and "\n"

Comment: If that answer (and the ones linked from there) doesn't help, please share what you've done in such a way that we can reproduce the problem. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Firebase stores strings exactly how they are sent. This means that the escaped string `\n` will not be stored as a new line character, but rather two characters next to each other (`\` and `n`).

What you can do is after you [retrieve](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) the string from Firebase, just replace `\n` with `\n`. This will replace the two characters with a new line character in an environment that will play nice with escaped characters.

I know it seems silly but this is absolutely a good thing to avoid some nasty people injecting things into your DB.